# How to merge two object arrays of differing length, based on two object key

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I have 2 arrays, I'd like to combine them if they have the same two object keys.

If no match is found, still keep the object, but have the value as 0.

**Example of Input**

```
withdrawal: [
    {
        "id": "a1",
        "withdrawalAmount": 300,
        "user": "John"
    },
    {
        "id": "b2",
        "withdrawalAmount": 100,
        "user": "Mike"
    }
    {
        "id": "c3",
        "withdrawalAmount": 33,
        "user": "John"
    }
]


deposit: [
    {
        "id": "a1",
        "depositAmount": 123,
        "user": "John"
    },
    {
        "id": "c3",
        "depositAmount": 44,
        "user": "John"
    },
]
```

**Expected Output**

```
transactions: [
    {
        "id": "a1",
        "depositAmount": 123,
        "withdrawalAmount": 300,
        "user": "John"
    },
    {
        "id": "b2",
        "depositAmount": 0,
        "withdrawalAmount": 100,
        "user": "Mike"
    },
    {
        "id": "c3",
        "depositAmount": 44,
        "withdrawalAmount": 33
        "user": "John"
    },
]
```

This is the function I tried so far, but it doesn't work due the two input arrays being a different length.

```
function mergeArrayObjects(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.map((item, i) => {
      if (item.user === arr2[i].user) {
        //merging two objects
        return Object.assign({}, item, arr2[i])
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: The approach used will ignore elements in `arr2` if those do not have a matching `id` in `arr1`. So, if the `arr2` array had an element like: `{"id" : "c3", "depositAmount": 333, "user": "tom"}` and `arr1` did not have a corresponding `c3` element, then this deposit will be excluded from transactions. May be this is what is needed? Please update the question to clarify.

Comment: @jsN00b Thanks for pointing it out, updated the question, I would like it to not ignore elements if it does not have a matching id, but have the value of the amount set to 0, like the expected output above.

Comment: What @jsN00b was saying is what happens if there is that entry in `deposit` for `id = 'c3'`, but there is no entry in `withdrawal` for `id = 'c3'`? Should there be an entry in `transactions` with `withdrawalAmount = 0`?

Comment: @Nick yes, correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the result you want by processing the list of withdrawals and deposits using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to an object with the `id` values as keys and `deposit` and `withdrawal` amounts as values; you can then take the values of that object to make the `transactions` array:

```js
const withdrawal = [{
    "id": "a1",
    "withdrawalAmount": 300,
    "user": "John"
  },
  {
    "id": "b2",
    "withdrawalAmount": 100,
    "user": "Mike"
  }
]

const deposit = [{
    "id": "a1",
    "depositAmount": 123,
    "user": "John"
  },
  {
    "id": "c3",
    "depositAmount": 44,
    "user": "John"
  }
]

const transactions = Object.values(
  withdrawal
    .concat(deposit)
    .reduce((c, { id, depositAmount, withdrawalAmount, ...rest }) => {
      c[id] = c[id] || {}
      depositAmount = c[id]['depositAmount'] || depositAmount || 0;
      withdrawalAmount = c[id]['withdrawalAmount'] || withdrawalAmount || 0;
      c[id] = ({ id, depositAmount, withdrawalAmount, ...rest });
      return c;
    },
    {})
  )
  
console.log(transactions)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

If you want to group by both `id` and `user`, you need to make the result object keys out of both values, joined by a character that is not in either of them (e.g. `#` would work for your data):

```js
const withdrawal = [{
    "id": "a1",
    "withdrawalAmount": 300,
    "user": "John"
  },
  {
    "id": "b2",
    "withdrawalAmount": 100,
    "user": "Mike"
  }
]

const deposit = [{
    "id": "a2",
    "depositAmount": 123,
    "user": "John"
  },
  {
    "id": "b2",
    "depositAmount": 109,
    "user": "Mike"
  },
  {
    "id": "c3",
    "depositAmount": 44,
    "user": "John"
  }
]

const transactions = Object.values(
  withdrawal
    .concat(deposit)
    .reduce((c, { id, user, depositAmount, withdrawalAmount, ...rest }) => {
      key = `${id}#${user}`
      c[key] = c[key] || {}
      depositAmount = c[key]['depositAmount'] || depositAmount || 0;
      withdrawalAmount = c[key]['withdrawalAmount'] || withdrawalAmount || 0;
      c[key] = ({ id, user, depositAmount, withdrawalAmount, ...rest });
      return c;
    },
    {})
  )
  
console.log(transactions)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Comment: What happens if `deposit` had another element like so: `{"id" : "c3", "depositAmount": 333, "user": "Nicholas"}` ? Does it get reflected in `transactions`? Guess OP was not clear whether such an entry needs to be included or discarded. :-)

Comment: @jsN00b a good question - sadly OP has failed to confirm the answer with their edit...

Comment: @jsN00b Yes, it will get reflected in `transactions`, and if for that particular `id` and `user`, his `"withdrawalAmount"` would be 0, since he only made deposits.

Comment: @BreadBoard.ini I've updated my answer to deal with that situation

Comment: @Nick Thanks for the answer, so far it is working for me, but what if I would like to join it based on `user` AND `id`, instead of only `id`?

Apologies if I reply too late

Comment: @BreadBoard.ini do you mean that you want to group (for example) `John` and `a3` separately from `Bill` and `a3`? i.e. there can be different `user` values for a given `id` value?

Comment: @Nick Yes, both `id` and `user` keys must be exactly the same if the two arrays would like to join, if only one matches, or both keys do not match, set the `depositAmount` or `withdrawalAmount` value to 0, accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Presented below is one possible way to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
// helper method to obtain all props 
// from array-elt matching "id"
const getInfo = (ar, argId) => (
  ar?.find(({ id }) => id === argId) ?? {}
);

// combine both arrays using "id"
const combineArrays = (ar1, ar2) => {
  // first get unique ids combining both arrays
  const uniqIds = [
    ...new Set(
      [...ar1, ...ar2]
      .map(({ id }) => id)
    )
  ];
  // now, for each unique id
  // simply get relevant info from both
  // arrays where element's match the "id"
  return uniqIds.map(id => ({
    id,
    ...getInfo(ar1, id),
    ...getInfo(ar2, id)
  }));
};

const withdrawal = [{
    "id": "a1",
    "withdrawalAmount": 300,
    "user": "John"
  },
  {
    "id": "b2",
    "withdrawalAmount": 100,
    "user": "Mike"
  }
];

const deposit = [{
  "id": "a1",
  "depositAmount": 123,
  "user": "John"
}];

// invoke the method and display the result
console.log(
  'combined both arrays as below:\n',
  combineArrays(withdrawal, deposit)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments added to the snippet above.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const withdrawal = [{
    "id": "a1",
    "withdrawalAmount": 300,
    "user": "John"
  },
  {
    "id": "b2",
    "withdrawalAmount": 100,
    "user": "Mike"
  }
]


const deposit = [{
  "id": "a1",
  "depositAmount": 123,
  "user": "John"
}, ]
const mergeArr = withdrawal.map(ele => {
  let other = deposit.find(({id}) => id === ele.id)
  return other ? {...ele, ...other} : {...ele, depositAmount : 0}
})
console.log(mergeArr)
```

Answer (score 1):

In first iteration merge only common object then re-iterate both array and take only un-used item in final array.

```js
class Transaction {
  constructor(transaction) {
    this.id = transaction.id;
    this.depositAmount = transaction.depositAmount | 0;
    this.withdrawAmount = transaction.withdrawalAmount | 0;
    this.user = transaction.user;
  }
}

let withdrawl = [
  {
    id: "a1",
    withdrawalAmount: 300,
    user: "John",
  },
  {
    id: "b2",
    withdrawalAmount: 100,
    user: "Mike",
  },
  {
    id: "c3",
    withdrawalAmount: 33,
    user: "John",
  },
];

let deposit = [
  {
    id: "a1",
    depositAmount: 123,
    user: "John",
  },
  {
    id: "c3",
    depositAmount: 44,
    user: "John",
  },
];


let transactions = [];

// merge the common key of two array into one array
withdrawl.forEach((item1) => {
  deposit.forEach((item2) => {
    if (item1.id === item2.id) {
      let combined = { ...item1, ...item2 };
      let transaction = new Transaction(combined);
      transactions.push(transaction);

      // mark the item as used
      // or set some flag to know
      // the item is used in the array
      item1.used = true;
      item2.used = true;
    }
  })
})

// now take all the unused item from the both array
// and push them to the transactions array
withdrawl.forEach((item1) => {
  if (!item1.used) {
    let transaction = new Transaction(item1);
    transactions.push(transaction);
  }
});

deposit.forEach((item2) => {
  if (!item2.used) {
    let transaction = new Transaction(item2);
    transactions.push(transaction);
  }
});

console.log(transactions);
```

Answer (score 1):

For large arrays go with Nick's [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72372048/2729605) (you will save a lot of cycles in the end)

For small amount of items in the array, a solution with `find()` can be good enough:

```js
const withdrawal= [
    {
        "id": "a1",
        "withdrawalAmount": 300,
        "user": "John"
    },
    {
        "id": "b2",
        "withdrawalAmount": 100,
        "user": "Mike"
    },
    {
        "id": "c3",
        "withdrawalAmount": 33,
        "user": "John"
    }
]


const deposit= [
    {
        "id": "a1",
        "depositAmount": 123,
        "user": "John"
    },
    {
        "id": "c3",
        "depositAmount": 44,
        "user": "John"
    }
]

const transactions = withdrawal.map(item => ({"depositAmount": 0, ...item}));

deposit.forEach( item => {
  const found = transactions.find(x => x.id === item.id);
  if (found) {
      Object.assign(found,item);
  } else {
    transactions.push(Object.assign(item,{"withdrawalAmount": 0}));
  }
  });


console.log(transactions)
```

NOTE: this code assumes that you want the union of both arrays rather than the intersection

Comment: Thx for the reply, only one thing is missing which is where the `id` is `b2`, i would like to display `depositAmount` as well, with 0 as the value. Since this user only made a withdrawal

Comment: then a default value is needed in both cases, i will edit my answer

Comment: @BreadBoard.ini now both _amount get a 0 value by default